# Connecting to a device in LAN over TCP/IP using C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, plc

I'm trying to connect to a device(Allen-Bradley PLC) residing in a LAN using C.
The device I'm trying to connect does not host an application that listens to my application (since I have no control over it).
Once the connection is established, I can send and receive packets requesting data. I already developed a working application in C# (using System.Net.Sockets) that connects and communicates with this device.
However, the C code I'm writing seems to fail at the part where it establishes connection. 
Here's my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <errno.h>


int main() {
char *servIP = "192.168.10.31";

in_port_t servPort = 503;

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (sock < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));

servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
if (rtnVal <= 0)
{
    printf("failed"); exit(1);
}

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
{
    printf("failed connecting"); exit(1);
}
else {
    printf("connected");
}

char x[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
printf("terE");
write(sock, x, sizeof(x));

char buffer[1024];
recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
printf("Data received: %s", buffer);


}
```

Comment: _seems to fail at the part where it establishes connection._ What error? could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Side note: are you sure that `buffer` is a null terminated C-strings?

Comment: @LPs The program exits out at "failed connecting" part. The buffer was just a spaghetti code to test if connection establishes first,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set the port for the call to `connect()`.

You defined a `servPort` variable, but you are not assigning it to the `servAddr` variable.

So you should add:

```
servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
```

or simply:

```
servAddr.sin_port = htons(503);
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the sin_port to you're code.

And you also forgot the WSAStartup. Look at this tutorial it might help:

http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/Winsock2example.html

Comment: The `s_addr` is being populated by the call to `inet_pton()` before `connect()`.  But you are right about needing `WSAStartup()` on Windows.